# SQL Select COUNT by multiples of 10

Tags: sql

I have a table with the following structure:

```
Referrals
ReferrerID  Date_Activated  ReferredID
INT     DateTime    INT
```

I would like to do an SQL COUNT, but I need to count multiples of 10.

So for example, if there are 34 entries by ReferrerID, I would like the count to return 3 (since there are only 3 multiples of 10).

Or, if there are 29 entries for ReferrerID X, I would like it to return 2 (since it's less than 30)

Comment: I tried COUNT and looking up GROUP by...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT
    FLOOR(COUNT(*) / 10) AS ten_count
FROM
    Referrals
```

Comment: @redconservatory but vc is right! you should try and keep those 90% up by checking the giant green check mark to the left of the question ;)

Comment: @vc sorry it was too early to hit the checkmark and I was away from my computer...I guess that's not allowed on stack overflow ;-0

Comment: @redconservatory, no need to apologize, I need to leave my desk sometimes too :)

Comment: @vc74 but only for very short moments at a time, right ;) makes me think of this for some reason: http://xkcd.com/208/